# Why does ping use ICMP not TCP?

Tags: tcp, ping, icmp

In our office we've got an Amazon VPC linked to our office network with a bastion server in the middle.

When I try to [`ping`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) servers within the VPC it doesn't work. The answer I got from a co-worker was that "ping won't work because [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) isn't linked in our routing configuration, only TCP."

(I can ping servers on our local business network, and Internet websites).

My question is: **Why does ping use ICMP not TCP?**

Comment: I have to wonder how one might fail to "setup UDP"...

Comment: It doesn't. It uses ICMP. Your co-worker is mistaken.

Comment: Your colleague is still mistaken. If ICMP wasn't 'linked in your routing configuration' a lot more wouldn't work than just `ping`. And why actually should `ping` use TCP in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are ping utilities which use ping-like features over TCP or UDP to test whether a target host answers connection attempts. One of these is Mark Russinovich's psping (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psping.aspx) which can use ICMP or TCP. Technically, it's not the same as ICMP as it's built upon the TCP handshake; in practice, you use it like ICMP ping.

Answer (score 3):

They belong to different layers in the OSI model.
ICMP is layer 3, for networking.
While TCP, UDP is layer 4, for transport.

Ping is echo request/reply, part of the layer 3.

Comment: This is the answer.  Ping is a lower level test than things that test tcp or udp.  Ping also predates udp by a lot.